# knockout.js augment context for each render in template binding

Tags: knockout.js, custom-binding

What I want to do, *I think* requires you to augment the individual bindingContexts of each rendered item in a foreach or template binding.

It can be done by instantiating a custom template engine extends the bindingContext in `renderTemplateSource`. But that seems hacky. There must be a better way.

What is this better way? That is my primary question.

I also want to add some bindings automatically to nodes in the anonymous templates of foreach bindings. This too, I can do with my custom template engine, but afaik that forces the automatic bindings to be added in the form of "data-bind" attribute strings. Also very funky.

Is there a cleaner way to let your custom bindings sneak in other bindings, on stuff that comes out of a foreach? That is my secondary question.

Below is a more detailed explanation of what I am trying to do. If you can suggest something cooler and cleaner, I thank you.

---

I am trying to write a custom binding called "uiList", to be used as such:

```
<ul data-bind="uiList: people">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span> 
    ...other stuff ...
  </li>
<ul>
```

Basically, an alias to "foreach". But I also want some typical list-widget-interactivity like "selecting" an item by clicking on it. And keeping only one item at a time selected.

To elaborate on my example, I would like to make people's names editable like so:

```
<ul data-bind="uiList: people">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name, visible: !$selected()"></span>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: name, visible: $selected()"> 
  </li>
<ul>
```

In other words, information like selectedness, disabledness et c, that relates to the ui of the list as a whole, but not to the data, should be made available in a clean and simple way on the binding context, as with the `$selected` property above.

For complete functionality my html could look like this:

```
<ul class="ui-list" data-bind="uiList: people">
  <li class="ui-list-item" data-bind="click: function () {$selected(true)}, css: $selected() ? 'ui-state-selected' : ''">
    <span data-bind="text: name, visible: !$selected()"></span>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: name, visible: $selected()"> 
  </li>
<ul>
```

... but that's the stuff I want uiList to automate.  A user should only need to write as in the previous example.

Here's how my custom binding handler code looks:

```
var ExtendedForeachTemplateEngine = function (contextExtender, bindings) {
    this.allowTemplateRewriting = false;
    this.contextExtender = contextExtender;

    //prep a data-bind="..." string from the given bindings to
    //sneak in on rendered anon templates
    this.bindingStr = [];
    for (var bindingName in bindings) {
        this.bindingStr.push(bindingName + ':' + bindings[bindingName]);
    }
    this.bindingStr = this.bindingStr.join(', ');
};

ExtendedForeachTemplateEngine.prototype = new ko.templateEngine();

ExtendedForeachTemplateEngine.prototype.renderTemplateSource = function (templateSource, bindingContext) {
    //extend the binding context
    this.contextExtender(bindingContext);

    //sneak in bindings rendered anon templates. Only on the first
    //Element node.
    var nodes = templateSource.nodes().cloneNode(true).childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i ++) {
        if (nodes[i].nodeType !== 1) continue;
        var nodeBindings = nodes[i].getAttribute('data-bind');
        if (nodeBindings) { 
            nodeBindings += ', ' + this.bindingStr;
        } else {
            nodeBindings = this.bindingStr; 
        }
        nodes[i].setAttribute('data-bind', nodeBindings);
        break;
    }
    return nodes;
}

/*
Takes data like a regular foreach. also takes a binding context-extender
callback function, and some bindings to add to each rendered template.
*/
ko.bindingHandlers['extendedForeach'] = {
    init: function (el, va, al, vm, bc) {
        var opts = va();
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(el, {
            template: {
                foreach: opts.data,
                templateEngine: new ExtendedForeachTemplateEngine(opts.contextExtender, opts.bindings)
            }
        }, bc);
    }
};

/*

uiList
-----------

Classes:
- adds class ui-list to the bound element
- renders the inner html for each given item.
- inner html gets ui-list-item class

Selection
- click on one of the rendered item and it is selected.
- context property $selected holds selectedness.
- selected items have class ui-state-selected,
- Only one item can be selected at a time.

*/
ko.bindingHandlers['uiList'] = {
    init: function (el, va, al, vm, bc) {
        var items = va();
        console.log(items);
        var selectedItem = ko.observable(null);
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(el, {
            extendedForeach: {
                data: items,
                bindings: {
                    css: "'ui-list-item' + ($selected() ? ' ui-state-selected' : '')",
                    click: "function () { $selected(true); }"
                },
                contextExtender:  function (context) {
                    context.$selected = ko.computed({
                        read: function () {
                            return selectedItem() === context.$index();
                        },
                        write: function (val) {
                            selectedItem(val ? context.$index() : null);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }, bc);
        $(el).addClass('ui-list');
        return {controlsDescendantBindings: true};
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a reusable viewmodel. That's the short answer.

The longer one is that you need a nice way of injecting the template for it otherwise you need to do that everywhere you use the model. One way is to use a library like my binding convention library,  that way it will automatically render the correct template/view depending on the view model.

Example,
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions/wiki/Template-convention

Another way is to encapsulate the reusable viewmodel in a custom binding and render the template for it using a custom template source.  You can look at my combobox for an example of that

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Combobox/blob/master/src/knockout.combobox.js#L345

Comment: You're probably right about making a reusable view model. That changes my question, though, into wether there is some way to instantiate a ListItemViewModel for each item rendered (separate from the "people" or individual person data). Such a view model could give you access to computed observables about selectedness without having to reference the parent (as your combobox example does), which I think would be elegant.

Comment: In your case its not possible for the item to know its select status without pollin its parent?

Comment: No, you're right - the reference would need to be there. I was just hoping it could be hidden in a computed observable. Because generally speaking the state in question might need to reference parents, or be computed from multiple context properties. And it would be nice to be able to hide all that from a user of the bindingHandler, and just say: "need to know if your list view item is selected? Ask the $selected property - we've already taken care of the logic for that!"

Comment: But isnt wrapping the data object in a wrapper ViewModel teh best way then, and let the 'ListViewModel' create those for each data item. Like I am doing in the combobox for my combobox items. The usee of the ListViewModel wont need todo anything then

Comment: Ah ok, now I see what you mean. Rather than looping over "people" and trying to inject stuff, I loop over something like new ListViewModel(people).items. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without customising anything.

In viewModel constructor

```
this.people = ko.observableArray(...);
// create holder for selected person
this.selectedPerson = ko.observable();
```

In HTML, (`click: $parent.selectedPerson` is possible, because `selectedPerson` is a function, ko will call `$parent.selectedPerson($data)` when clicked)

```
<ul class="ui-list" data-bind="foreach: people">
  <li class="ui-list-item" data-bind="click: $parent.selectedPerson,
    css: { 'ui-state-selected': $parent.selectedPerson() === $data }">
    <span data-bind="text: name, visible: $parent.selectedPerson() !== $data"></span>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: name, visible: $parent.selectedPerson() === $data"> 
  </li>
<ul>
```

If you want to hide those extra detail from HTML, instead of using customised bindingHandler, a better way is to use knockout 3.2.0-beta new feature on component, which allows you to encapsulate internal model (like the selectedPerson) and HTML template together.
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/06/11/architecting-large-single-page-applications-with-knockout-js/

Comment: Sure I could keep the state inside the viewmodel. But the point was to write something reusable which encapsulates the logic of "selecting something in a list" without caring about what a list item looks like or what data it's bound to. The component feature looks interesting.

Comment: Thinking more about it, I think you're right about putting the data in a view model somehow. Rather than trying to extend the context. It's data about the view, after all. Would upvote for suggesting components, but I don't have the rep.